# Strapi: Warning an error occurred while requesting the API

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, strapi

I've been struggling for hours trying to install Strapi on my Ubuntu server.

> Ubuntu:  20.04
> nodejs:  v14.19.0
> npm:     6.14.16
> strapi:  4

```
npx create-strapi-app@latest my-project --quickinstall
```

All the installation process goes seamlessly but when I go to http://mydomain:1337/admin in order to create a first user I get this warning:

> an error occurred while requesting the API.

I know this problem has been encountered several times but none of the suggested solutions have helped me so far.
I also found this error in the Chrome console but I'm not not sure it's related to the my problem:

> ﻿main.815f1087.js:2 Refused to connect to
> 'http://localhost:1337/admin/project-type' because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'
> https:".

Any idea ?

Answer (score 31):

You need to build the app. [Read this github issue](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/12129)

Run: `npm run build` or `yarn build` or `strapi build` depending on what you are using

Comment: This did it for me. Running on windows, though.

Answer (score 5):

I had this error after upgrading to latest Strapi and all dependencies, what helped me, is to rebuild the Strapi admin interface:

```
yarn build
```

or

```
npm run build
```

then start develop

```
yarn develop
```

or

```
npm run develop
```

Answer (score 1):

First Build your Application by using `npm run build` then run `npm start`.

Answer (score 1):

What I did is to change the host address from 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1 in server.js and then ran `npm run build` and that fixed my issue. I know it sounds strange but it worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running strapi CMS on docker, and using docker composer to build, then maintain the default port 1337 when binding the container port to your system port.

> Do this: -1337:1337
>
> Not this: -8000:13337

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem, a simple restart of the server did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, need to **Build the admin panel** and then **Start the application**.

To build the admin panel,

```
npm run build
# or
yarn build
```

To start the application with auto-reload,

```
npm run develop
# or
yarn develop
```

Answer (score 0):

when you change the port of your strapi app, you must run `npm run build` or `yarn build` or `strapi build`. because strapi admin templates use default port `1337` and for using on another port you must build the project again.

Answer (score 0):

Running `strapi` on a server (& behind a reverse-proxy) - you need to set the `url`:

```
# path: config/server.js


module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  url: 'https://my.example.com',
});
```

- rebuild the Admin Panel: `npm run build`
- start the `dev` server: `npm run develop`

---

Also useful - run a production build: `NODE_ENV=production npm run build`

Answer (score 0):

Well, first thing to do is add url in server.js at "./config/server.js". Also add proxy: true eg:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  app: {
    keys: env.array('APP_KEYS'),
  },
  webhooks: {
    populateRelations: env.bool('WEBHOOKS_POPULATE_RELATIONS', false),
  },
  proxy: true,
  url: "https://yoursite.com",
});
```

Now change admin.js at "./config/admin.js"
eg:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  auth: {
    secret: env('ADMIN_JWT_SECRET'),
  },
  apiToken: {
    salt: env('API_TOKEN_SALT'),
  },
  transfer: {
    token: {
      salt: env('TRANSFER_TOKEN_SALT'),
    },
  },
  port: 1337,
  url: "https://yoursite.com/admin"
});
```

Note: https is required else you will get error in console something like:

```
Refused to connect to 'http://yourwebsite/admin/project-type' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' https:".
```

Refused to connect to 'http://yourwebsite/admin/init' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' https:".

If you do not have https you might have to change middleware, please see example below security section in strapi documentation:
https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/configurations/middlewares#security

Very Imp: Lastly you must build strapi app other wise above configuration change will not apply. Make sure you do this:

```
NODE_ENV=production npm run build
or
NODE_ENV=production yarn run build
```