# Making fetch request in the latest version of NextJS results in 'fetch failed'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, strapi

I building nextjs (v.13.4.19) / strapi (v.4.12.5) app and having trouble with making a request to strapi endpoint using fetch function. I already tried:

- change `localhost:1337` into `127.0.0.1:1337`
- change node version on strapi backend side to 14/16/18
- move fetch request to strapi under nextjs `api` project structure

Neither of them seems to works. For a test, I googled a random api endpoint returning a json value and it turns out that it works. So the problem is probably strictly related to strapi.

```
import React from "react";

export const getItems = async () => {
  try {
    const wearResponse = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:1337/api/items/?populate=*`
    ); // here exception is occuring

    if (!wearResponse.ok) throw new Error("failed to fetch items");

    return wearResponse.json();
  } catch (err: any) {
    console.error("Error occurred:", err);
  }
};

export default async function Page() {
  const itemsList = await getItems();
  return (
    <>
      <h2>...</h2>
    </>
  );
}
```

I getting an following error:

```
Error occurred: TypeError: fetch failed ... 
{
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 1337
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a strapi api token in your `fetch` call.

```
const wearResponse = await fetch(
  `http://localhost:1337/api/items/?populate=*`,
  { headers: { Authorization: `bearer <api token>` } }
);
```

> When performing a request to Strapi's REST API, the API token should be added to the request's Authorization header with the following syntax: bearer your-api-token.
>
> https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/configurations/api-tokens#usage

You can create a new api token via https://docs.strapi.io/user-docs/settings/API-tokens#creating-a-new-api-token

Comment: It still not working. I getting response using Postman even without passing token in the request. Also it works in pure react but not in nextjs

Comment: @Telirw Do you have a github repo I can take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the strapi admin interface. Run `npm run build` or `yarn build`

[read this stack overflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70957481/strapi-warning-an-error-occurred-while-requesting-the-api)